# google.script.run to reload google chart in HTML-service page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

Just like I would inject new html on a div using google.script.run on a page without reloading, I have spent countless hours trying to do the same but with a google-visualization pie chart, I want to call as many times as needed this google.run.script through a callback.

This is the button with multiple callbacks:

```
 <button onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(refresh).report(user());">Generate report</button>
```

OK, this is what user do:

```
<script>
function user() {
var user = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
return user;
}

</script>
```

Report() simply returns a new array of data for a chart, it will change depending on user.

Finally this is my chart script.

```
<script>
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], "callback": refresh});
google.setOnLoadCallback(refresh);

function refresh(e) {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(e);

 var options = {
          title: 'Chart',
          is3D: true,
   pieSliceText: 'label',
        };

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

        }
</script>
```

My script works as intended all the way, except the end where I can't get it to update the chart everytime I click the button. Which loads new array data for the chart. I have simplified the code just for this post.

Comment: any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: This [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hp65hqb8/4/) based on your code works as expected. The major difference being, I don't get the data using `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(refresh).report(user())`. My assumption is the error lies there.

Comment: I managed to fix it by using JSON.parse on the callback value for some strange reason, and now it works as intended!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work as intended by parsing the callback value with JSON.parse(e), very hidden for me to figure it out.